# Python 2.7 - Add user inputed number to current time?

Tags: python, time, input

So basically I need to add a number that the user inputs, I'm just using raw_input, and I want to add that number, in minutes, to the current time.

So:

```
breakTime = int(raw_input("How long do you want to have a break for?"))
```

And I want to add whatever they type to

```
datetime.datetime.now()
```

Is this possible?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`datetime.timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) for that:

```
import datetime
minutes = int(raw_input("break time"))
dt = datetime.timedelta(minutes = minutes)
later = datetime.datetime.now() + dt
```

Comment: Consider adding validation to this.  While the timedelta API allows for a negative value to be specified for minutes, your application shouldn't allow someone to take a break for a negative amount of time :)

Comment: Genius mglison, thanks! :D

How do you add validation AJ?  Is there some way to make sure they don't input negative numbers?

Comment: @tommo -- just check to make sure that `minutes` is bigger than 0.  If it isn't, ask again.  You can put the whole thing in an infinite `while` loop which has a `break` when minutes > 0 if you'd like.  e.g. `while True: minutes = int(raw_input("break time")); if minutes > 0: break`.  (I'll leave it to you to figure out the indentation ;-).